# Find all $x$ to satisfy $|x-a|<|x-b|$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, absolute-value, functional-inequalities

### Exercise:

> Using signs of inequality alone (not using signs of absolute value) specify the values of $x$ which satisfy the following relation. Discuss all cases.
>   $$|x-a|<|x-b|$$

---

### Solution:

$|x-a|<|x-b| \tag{1}$

Since $RHS \geq 0$ in (1): $-|x-b|<x-a<|x-b| \tag{2}$

Split (2): $-|x-b|<x-a \tag{3}$
$x-a<|x-b| \tag{4}$

Working on (3): $|x-b|<a-x \tag{5}$

For (5) to be valid: $RHS \geq 0 \implies a-x\geq 0 \implies x \leq a \tag{6}$

Since $RHS \geq 0$ in (5): $-(a-x)<x-b<a-x \implies x-a<x-b<a-x \tag{7}$

Split (7):
$x-a<x-b \implies -a<-b \implies a>b \tag{8}$

$x-b<a-x \implies x<\frac{a+b}{2} \tag{9}$

Working on (4); due to (6): $LHS \leq 0 \tag{10}$

Due to (10), $0 < |x-b| \implies x \neq b \tag{11}$

---

### Answer:

$$a > b \tag{a}$$
$$x < \frac{a+b}{2} \tag{b}$$
$$x \neq b \tag{c}$$

---

### Request:

**Is my answer correct? If so, can my answer be any more specific?**

---

### Update:

As per @Bernard's hint, here is my new attempt.

$|x-a|<|x-b|$

$(x-a)^2<(x-b)^2$

$x^2-2ax+a^2<x^2-2bx+b^2$

$-2ax+a^2<-2bx+b^2$

$a^2-b^2<2ax-2bx$

$(a-b)(a+b)<2(a-b)x$

$a+b<2x$

$$\frac{a+b}{2}<x$$

I feel as if I "lost information" when interchanging the absolute values with squares. Is this so?

Comment: It' need not be true that $a > b$. Consider for example $a = 0$, $b = 1$, $x = 0$. One way to approach this (assuming $x$, $a$, and $b$ are real) is to note that $|x-a| < |x-b|$ if and only if $(x-a)^2 < (x-b)^2$.

Comment: You only have part of the answer. What if $a<b$?

Comment: Regarding your update, everything is OK through the line $(a-b)(a+b) < 2(a-b)x$. Presumably you divided both sides by $a-b$ to conclude that $a+b < 2x$. However, this is only valid if $a-b > 0$. If $a-b < 0$, then you are dividing by a negative number, which reverses the inequality. Also consider the possibility that $a=b$.

Comment: @Bungo -- Oh, I see. I knew that something was wrong (due to the different answer as compared with the answers below) but I wasn't sure where I made the mistake. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. you did not lose information by replacing the absolute values with squares. This is because for any real numbers $c$ and $d$, we have $|c| < |d|$ if and only if $c^2 < d^2$.

Comment: (5) is wrong: multiplying by $-1$ flips the inequality.  So
$$
-|x-b| < x-a \iff |x-b| > a-x \, .
$$

Comment: You made a similar mistake in your updated version.  What if $a-b < 0$?  Then canceling $a-b$ is dividing by a negative number, so the inequality will switch.  You can deal with this by considering the cases $a > b$ and $a < b$ separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have it in a much simpler way if you eliminate the absolute values.

**Hint:**

$$\lvert A\rvert <\lvert B\rvert \iff A^2 <B^2.$$

Comment: See update to question. Did I use your hint correctly (and end up with the right answer)?

Comment: The only thing you're missing is cancellation of $a-b$: if it is negative, you have to change the sense of the inequality. Explicitly, if $a<b$, you find $\dfrac{a+b}2>x$.

Answer (score 3):

Interpreting the expressions inside the absolute values as distances is very helpful. More precisely, $|x-a|$ is the distance from $x$ to $a$, and $|x-b|$ is the distance from $x$ to $b$. Therefore you are looking for the real numbers $x$ that are closer to $a$ (than to $b$).

For the three possible cases, you get immediatly:

(1) $a<b$: the interval $(-\infty,\frac{a+b} 2)$.

(2) $a=b$: the empty set.

(3) $a>b$: the interval $(\frac{a+b} 2,\infty)$.