# Find $x$ such that $|x-a|<x-b$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, absolute-value, functional-inequalities

Earlier, I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056304/find-all-x-to-satisfy-x-ax-b), and received great answers. Now, I'm attempting another, similar problem.

---

### Exercise:

> Using signs of inequality alone (not using signs of absolute value) specify the values of $x$ which satisfy the following relation. Discuss all cases.
>   $$|x-a|<x-b$$

---

### Attempt:

*RE exercise:* $|x-a|<x-b \tag{1}$

*RE (1):* $RHS \geq 0$ to be defined; so: $x \geq b \tag{2}$

*RE (1):* $RHS \geq 0$ to be defined; so: $|x-a|<|x-b| \tag{3}$

*RE (3)*: According to previous exercise *(see link above)*:

$x > \frac{a+b}{2} \space\text{when}\space a>b \tag{4}$

$x < \frac{a+b}{2} \space\text{when}\space a<b \tag{5}$

$x \space\text{undefined when}\space a=b \tag{6}$

*RE (2), (4) & (6):* $x \geq b > \frac{a+b}{2} \space\text{when}\space a>b \tag{7}$

*RE (7):* Simplified: $x > b \space\text{when}\space a>b \tag{8}$

---

### Answer:

*RE (5), (6), & (8):*

$$x < \frac{a+b}{2} \space\text{when}\space a<b$$
$$x \space\text{undefined when}\space a=b$$
$$x > b \space\text{when}\space a>b$$

---

### Request:

**Is my answer correct? If not, where'd I go wrong?**

Comment: @Macavity -- I'm not quite understanding you. Don't I already cover all relationships of $a$ and $b$ ($=$, $>$, $<$)?

Comment: @mathlove -- Oh, I see. But, where'd I go wrong?

Comment: Statement (7) is where you went wrong.  When $a> b$, $\frac{a+b}2 > b$.

Comment: @Macavity -- Yes, I see where I went wrong, but why? I thought that I'd want the larger of $b$ and $\frac{a+b}{2}$ since the range $[\frac{a+b}{2}, b]$ is covered by only one of those two inequalities.

Comment: One observation which might make things easier by eliminating the absolute value: note that $|x-a| < x - b$ is equivalent to $-(x-b) < x - a < x - b$.

Comment: @Bungo -- I did eliminate it: from (3) to (4). See link of previous problem.

Comment: @SirJony Note that $-(x-b) < x-a < x-b$ in turn is equivalent to BOTH of the following inequalities being true: $-(x-b) < x-a$ and $x - a < x - b$. The second of these in particular shows that there can't be a solution if $a \leq b$.

Comment: Draw a diagram - becomes obvious then.

Comment: @Bungo -- OK, I see in this case. However, when I tried this in my previous problem, I was given an incomplete answer. Why the inconsistency?

Comment: @SirJony In your previous problem, we have $|x-a| < |x-b|$. Using the same technique as above would give you $-|x-b| < x-a < |x-b|$, which is equivalent to both of these inequalities being true: $-|x-b| < x-a$ and $x-a < |x-b|$. In order to get rid of the absolute values you would now have to apply the same technique again to both inequalities. The method in your previous problem which used $|x-a| < |x-b|$ if and only if $(x-a)^2 < (x-b)^2$ makes things much easier. (That method can't be applied to **this** problem, however, because only one side has an absolute value.)

Comment: @Bungo -- OK. To clarify: I could use **this** method on the previous one (but it being more tedious than the other one proposed)?

Comment: @SirJony Yes, I think it would work out - why not give it a try? If you get stuck you could always create a new question (this comment section is becoming a bit cluttered).

Comment: @Bungo -- OK, I'll go do that. On a note to all: Thanks to all three answer! They were all helpful, using unique methods. However, I've decided to check-mark Macavity's because his was the closest to my attempt, correcting only where I had gone wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there were a lot of steps, showing the right expression in green below, and showing unnecessary or wrong steps in red:

### Your Attempt:

*RE exercise:* $|x-a|<x-b \tag{1}$

*RE (1):* $\color{green}{RHS > 0}$ to be defined; so: $\color{green}{x > b} \tag{2}$

*RE (1):* $RHS \geq 0$ to be defined $\color{red}{\text{unnecessary step}}$; so: $|x-a|<|x-b| \tag{3}$

*RE (3)*: According to previous exercise *(see link above)*:

$x > \frac{a+b}{2} \space\text{when}\space a>b \tag{4}$

$x < \frac{a+b}{2} \space\text{when}\space a<b \tag{5}$
$\color{green}{\text{But this (5) cannot give solutions as }\frac{a+b}2 < b \text{ in this case..}}$

$x \space \color{red}{\text{undefined when}}\color{green}{\text{ has no solutions when}}\space a=b \tag{6}$

*RE (2), (4) & (6):* $x \color{red}{\geq b} > \frac{a+b}{2} \color{green}{> b} \space\text{when}\space a>b \tag{7}$
$\color{green}{\text{Note }\frac{a+b}2 > b \text{ in this case..}}$

*RE (7):* Simplified: $\color{red}{x > b}\color{green}{ \quad x > \frac{a+b}2} \space\text{when}\space a>b \tag{8}$

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh! My only was that I (stupidly) claimed $b >\frac{a+b}{2}$ when $a > b$. I think you guys overcomplicated things in the comments under the question. :) Thanks, though!

Answer (score 4):

Expanding my comment into an answer:

We can eliminate the absolute value as follows. Observe that for any real numbers $c$ and $d$, the inequality $|c| < d$ means precisely that both $c < d$ and $-c < d$, or equivalently, that 
$$-d < c < d$$
Applying this to your problem, with $c = x-a$ and $d = x-b$, we see that $|x-a| < x-b$ is equivalent to
$$-(x-b) < x-a < x-b$$
This in turn is equivalent to **both** of the following inequalities being true:
$$-(x-b) < x-a$$
and
$$x-a < x-b$$
We can simplify the first inequality as follows:
$$-(x-b) < x-a \quad \iff \quad x >  (a+b)/2$$
and the second inequality as:
$$x-a < x-b \quad \iff \quad a > b$$
This means that there is no solution if $a \leq b$, whereas if $a > b$, any $x$ satisfying $x > (a+b)/2$ is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would always recommend drawing a picture first:

- Case 1: $a>b$

[image]
You can see that $|x-a|<x-b$ for values of $x$ to the right of the intersection of the lines $y=x-b$ and $y=a-x$.

Equating the two gives: $x-b=a-x \Rightarrow 2x=a+b \Rightarrow x=\frac {a+b}2$.

So $|x-a|<x-b$ for $x>\frac {a+b}2$

- Case 2: $a=b$

[image]
You can see that there are no instances where $|x-a|<x-b$

- Case 3: $a<b$

[image]
You can see that there are no instances where $|x-a|<x-b$